# Remove the Parent Div, but not what's inside the parent.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, I'm not sure if this is possible but anyway. Say for example:

```
<div id="foo">
    <a href="#" id="bar">Remove Parent</a>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#bar').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }); 
});
```

Is it possible that you can remove the parent container, in this example `#foo` but keep the child anchor tag `#bar`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this situation you'd be looking for [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

example...

```
$(function() {
    $('#bar').click(function() {
        $(this).unwrap();
    });
});
```

Comment: I figured it would be something like that, I just didn't know it existed, maybe I should have done a little more research about it prior to asking. But to be honest, searching for an answer to this you get some horrible google results.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
$(function() {
    $('#bar').click(function() {
        $("#bar").insertAfter("#foo");
    }); 
});
```