# jQuery remove tags either side of a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I remove the p tags outside of this div (I do *not* want to remove the test div).

```
<p>
  <div class='test'>
    content here
    <img />
  </div>
</p>
```

The result I'd like would be...

```
<div class='test'>
  content here
  <img />
</div>
```

I know there's a similar question here: [jQuery: How do I remove surrounding div tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454451/jquery-how-do-i-remove-surrounding-div-tags), but not got it to work in my situation

I've tried

```
$('p .test').replaceWith($('.test));
```

But of course that just selects the salon-slideshow div, rather than the p before it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove the Parent Div, but not what's inside the parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201834/remove-the-parent-div-but-not-whats-inside-the-parent)

Comment: Btw. having a `div` inside a `p` is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it but remember that it will affect all divs with `class="test"`

```
$("div.test").unwrap();
```

Comment: Great thanks, If it helps anyone I also had to make sure it was fired at $(document).ready.

Comment: Yes, you can use a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` structure or the even simpler `$(function(){...})`.

Answer (score 5):

The method you are looking for is called `.unwrap()` check out the documentation : http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.salon-slideshow').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().replaceWith($(this));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent());
    $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

Comment: -1 : because .unwrap() is a much more better and common way to do this.

Comment: Never used unwrap() before. Thanks for the info. Still my answer is not incorrect, just that its not the best answer.. :)