# get absolute height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an html element and it has some css which are applied on it on the fly
i want to know the exact height and width it takes after a new css class is applied. I tried `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` but they didnt included `padding` and `margin` properties of the element.

How to get the exact value without actually calculating it? can it be done with a `css` property directly?

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight) the `offsetHeight` property (and similarly width) is meant to include the border, padding, perpendicular scrollbar and actual rendered height. Perhaps your question ought to be how to make my code correct/cross-browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery makes it easy for you: http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: provide a bit code otherwise some will downvote this ! just a hint ;-)

Comment: what if i dont want to use jQuery as if i only need to get the outerWidth there is no need to call jQuery library for this. it will take a server trip as well as some amount of size while loading the page

Comment: what do you mean by server trip ? jquery is the best way to make code in javascript and it helps you in many many ways +1

Comment: @EvilP The jQuery website provides documentation and examples for this function. [:)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210165/jquery-remove-tags-either-side-of-a-div/9210186#9210186)

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be done in a cross-browser way: The point is, that you do not want to *know the exact height and width* of the **element** itself, but of the **space** it uses. This simply is a calculated value from the box model.

Either you need to calculate it yourself, or have a JS framework do it for you: Dojo and jQuery both have utility functions for that.