# True width of an element

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a very wide `<p>` element with `nowrap` that extends beyond the visible area.  I'm trying to find the width of it.  I believe that`clientWidth` and `offsetWidth` are only giving me the visible area (in Firefox and Chrome) because when I resize the window making it narrower, the values returned get smaller.

I was thinking of programatically getting the font face and size and trying to calculate width somehow.  I don't want to use hard coded values for font face and size in case I change the font face or size later.

How do I find the width of the paragraph with javascript that is compatible across browsers?  I prefer javascript because I know nothing about jquery.  Nothing.

```
<p id="Long" style="white-space:nowrap;">Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string Some super huge string
</p>
<script>
var w = document.getElementById("Long");
document.write(w.offsetWidth); //doesn't work
document.write(w.clientWidth); //doesn't work
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276633/get-absolute-height-and-width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('Long').scrollWidth
```

- [Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth)
- [A related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764658/how-to-get-the-overflowed-width-of-an-element-in-a-webpage)